# Positioning stuff with css, independent of the page size

Tags: css, positioning

So I've read a couple of CSS guides and understood most properties, but I still can't position elements PROPERLY.

What I mean by properly: right now I position stuff using specific values of`margin`, `margin-right`, `margin-left`, `padding`, (`margin-left:50px`), etc... What this means is that my `div`s are all positioned properly when I view it in my own computer with a specific resolution.

So I hope this isn't too general, but how do I position stuff in a way that they will be in the same relative spot in the page, for every resolution/page size, no matter who and what views it (I guess if it's the same for 99% of cases it's also a good start).

A bit more specific: which **properties** can I use to position elements in the manner I described?

Here's a link of one of my little projects which are badly positioned (it's all good in my screen, but not so much on others:
http://kash.hostzi.com/utopia/minesweeper.html

check out `#gameTable`'s css for example - I wanted to center that and did it in a horrible way.

Comment: "which properties can I use to position elements in the manner I described?" Any of them. There are not specific properties for doing this. It is a mindset and the use of units such as `em` and percent.

Comment: "So I hope this isn't too genera". It is. Please post some code of what you're experiencing.

Comment: Either have a container with a fixed width that will be the same on all systems (since it's fixed). Or use a liquid layout (everything is specified in percentages).

Comment: why would you want to do that? unless you also then change the font and image sizes dependant on your viewport size, your page will look really stupid and the layout will break anyway

Comment: I've added an example with which I've had positioning problems...

Comment: Why not just center #gameTable then? Vertical and horizontal positioning is not that hard. Use `margin: 0 auto;` for horizontal centering, and `top: 50%; margn-top: -(half the element height in px);` for vertical centering.

Comment: @Terry - the horizontal and vertial centering each work on their own, but when I combine them together the horizontal one fails. Any idea why?

Comment: @frrlod Ah, I forgot that combining two wouldn't work because using absolute positioning takes the element out of the document flow... instead, see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/fRSZb/

Answer (score 1):

In your linked example, it looks like you want the gameboard to be centered.  If it's a block-level element, such as a div or table, and you want to center it, you can use this on the element itself:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

If it's an inline element, and you want to center it, you can use this on the *parent* element:

```
text-align: center;
```

If you weren't trying to center it, but just want to have the position scale with the **screen size**, do something like this:

```
margin-left: 10%;
margin-right: 10%;
```

If you want the position to scale with the **font size**, do something like this:

```
margin-left: 10ex;
margin-right: 10ex;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start using percentages. Like:

```
margin-left: 20%;
margin-right: 20%;
```

and it will be margined depending on the window(the element in which it is) size.